# Hi I'm using BuddyX theme with the buddyboss platform plugin. Problem is, it's not showing the number of 'likes' on the posts in activites or groups

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, themes, buddypress

I'm using the BuddyX theme with the buddy boss platform plugin because the buddy boss premium theme is currently costly for me. With the BuddyX theme, it's not showing the number of 'likes' on the posts in activities or groups. Whereas, with any other theme, it's showing the number of likes. Also, I don't want to use any other theme. Please help me with what to do to fix that thing?

Answer (score 0):

Oh yea, After a update, it's now showing wow.